# Editing a long list of words in Notepad++

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I have a long list of words, one word per line. I want to paste `cw|` before each word on every line. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you don't have to post it twice, correct the punctuation, add some examples as to what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert text in the beginning of each line try this:
**UPDATED**

```
Open Replace dialog (Search->Replace)
    Check "Regular expression" flag in "Search Mode" panel.
    Enter "^(.+)$" (line ending symbol) in "Find what" field.
    Enter "cw|\1" (your text+\1) in "Replace with:" field.
    Press "Replace All"
```

[image: Regular expressions]

 You can also run replace in the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Press control + H, replace `^` with `cw|`.
Make sure you are in regular expression mode.

Comment: Care to explain how this works?

Comment: This is using regular expressions. `^` in regular expressions speak means "match start of string". Since you only want to match all start of each line, there is no need to specify anything after the `^`.